# Multiple smart contacts on same near wallet account

Tags: ethereum, nearprotocol, wallet

As per the near documentation, smart contract is deployed to the account - which is my wallet account.

How does this work in case of multiple smart contract? Is it possible to deploy multiple smart contract with the same wallet account and reference each of these smart contract in my product sth similar to Ethereum.

Execute scenario

1. Deploy a smart contract A with wallet **account B**
2. Deploy a smart contract C with wallet **account B**
3. Try to read the function of contract A. It throws error in Near blockchain.

In ethereum it works with smart contract address.

Q: Is it possible to read the methods of smart contract A with wallet account B?

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up I explored it more. A smart contract is deployed to a near account. It means technically a near account can't have the more than one smart contract. We access the smart contract methods with <account_name>.method_name_of_the_contract

Comment: Hi @Nagendra Kumar - I appreciate the follow up but does this answer the original question - "Q: Is it possible to read the methods of smart contract A with wallet account B."?

Comment: yes the follow up is the  answer. I am unblocked now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I´m not understanding the question right, but the answer is:

Yes, you can read the methods from a contract with another wallet.

Even you can call those methods, you need to add the logic to your Smart Contract for avoid specific wallets or whitelist wallets if you´re making something private.